# Way to bypass video upload when testing using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg

I'm testing a page on my app that shows videos. I'm trying to speed up the test by bypassing the video upload process or another way??

Maybe I'm using FactoryGirl incorrectly for file uploads..

Using FactoryGirl, I'm creating the video with

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :video do
  user_id 1
  type "Live"
  title "FooBar"
  description "Foo bar is the description"
  video { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'files', 'concert.mov'), 'video/mp4') }
 end
end
```

And in the request's spec I'm describing the videos as:

```
describe "videos page" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:video1) { FactoryGirl.create(:video) }

  before { visit user_video_path(user) }

  it { should have_title(user.name) }
  it { should have_content(user.name) }

  describe "videos" do
    it { should have_content(video1.description) }
  end
end
```

Now, everytime I run the test for this page it goes through the file upload process which takes more time. I'm also using FFmpeg

```
**video.rb (video model)**

validates :video, presence: true
has_attached_file :video, :styles => {
                                      :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4' },
                                      :thumb => { :geometry => "470x290#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
                                     }, 
                          :processors => [:ffmpeg]
```

What this does when I test the page is the CLI goes through the video upload process like it would if you were uploading the video and watching your local server.

Answer (score 0):

Override the video property with some value that passed all the validations and requirements that you need for the test when creating the object using the factory. For a concrete type you can use a [double](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs). Try something like this

```
file = double('file', :size => 0.2.megabytes, :content_type => 'mp4', :original_filename => 'rails')
let!(:video1) { FactoryGirl.create(:video, video => file) }
```

Comment: The video attribute's presence is required though

Comment: I then get the error `Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError:
       No handler found for "something"`

Comment: I updated my answer. Creating a double of type video should be fine.